# Firebase cloud function, send mail without AUTH

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My website is hosted on Firebase and I wish to send an email from like `no-reply@mydomain.com` to the recipient. Am I forced to create this email and provide login info for SMTP connection or is there a way I can send the mail without actually creating it (without the AUTH credentials), somewhat like `mail()` in PHP.

Presently, I am sending mail from my GMail with `nodemailer`:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://USER@gmail.com:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com');

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var mailOptions = {
        to: 'someone@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Test Mail',
        html: 'Testing the Mail'
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            res.end('Mail not sent');
        } else {
            res.end('Mail sent');
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a way out? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with Sendgrid, as follows. Here is the node.js library documentation:https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs

Sendgrid is an option that is recommended by Firebase, see https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/quickstarts/email-users, where it is said:

> If you are planning on sending a large number of emails you should use
>   a professional email sending platform such as Sendgrid, Mailjet or
>   Mailgun.

There is a "generous" free plan with 12.000 free emails a month, see https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/sendgrid-app/sendgrid-email

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

......

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const sengridkey =
  'SG.............................................';
sgMail.setApiKey(sengridkey);

......

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const msg = {
    to: 'someone@gmail.com',
    from: 'originator@gmail.com',     //  <-  HERE, set the from
    subject: 'Test Mail',
    html: '<h1>Test Mail</h1>',
  };

   sgMail
     .send(msg)
     .then(() => {
         res.status(200).send('Mail sent');
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.error('ERROR:', err);
         res.status(500).send('Mail not sent: ' + err);
      });

});
```

---

Note that you need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" Firebase pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

Since Sendgrid is not a Google-owned service, you need to switch to the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out and let you know. BTW, do I need to verify my domain with send grid before it allows me to send mails with it?

Comment: No, no need to verify the domain (from my experience).

Comment: I followed the link, setup billing. Now it tells me to REGISTER ACCOUNT, but I already have one! What to do now? How can I link my existing sendgrid account with gcloud?

Comment: You just need to get the Sengrid key. I don't think there is any "link with gcloud" unless the fact that you get a special price (or special free plan) if you use this link from the GCP console.

Comment: Also, note that you need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" Firebase pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

Since Sendgrid is not a Google-owned service, you need to switch to the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan.

Comment: Got this: `Mail not sent: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443`

Comment: https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-nodejs/issues/35. See my comment about Firebase pricing plan above.

Comment: Moving to Flame or Blaze defeats the whole purpose of switching to Firebase. Does the `nodemailer` allow sending mails from NON-GMAIL accounts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184271/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-saibbyweb).

Comment: @saibbyweb "Moving to Flame or Blaze defeats the whole purpose of switching to Firebase." You'll still get the same free quota on the Blaze plan. But, to prevent abuse, your project must be on a paid plan to be able to call external APIs.

Comment: There's no free quota for external API calls in Blaze plan, right? Charged at $0.12/GB

Comment: Do these Google Cloud function run outside of firebase as well?

Comment: @saibbyweb Actually, THERE IS a free quota for external API calls in Blaze plan. If you go to the Pricing page and hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title you will read that "On the Blaze plan, Cloud Functions provides a perpetual free tier. The first 2,000,000 invocations, 400,000 GB-sec, 200,000 CPU-sec, **and 5 GB of Internet egress traffic is provided for free each month**. You are only charged on usage past this free allotment."

Comment: I believe send grid API calls get counted in `Outbound networking` which are charged at $0.12/GB

Comment: Actually, egress is equal to Outbound data transfer, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#networking. With Blaze you get the free quotas of the "standard" Google Cloud Functions, including a free 5GB of Internet egress traffic per month